# How to update data in python file, from another?

Tags: python, json, import

I'm trying to create simple 'accounter', which can show your cash balance and logs of operations. Operations are simple: receive(amount, subject) and spend(amount, subject). They change balance and write the changes into logs with a timestamp. Should've.

I'm trying to use another .py file as a database. Although I can import, read and use database, I can't seem to find a way to write changes into it. Couldn't find any solution that I need anywhere. There are some ways like using json, and other. But I am trying to use exactly py file.

Here's db.py:

```
balance = 0

balance_logs = [
    ['305', 'spent','5','coke','2020-08-18 20:00'],
    ['202', 'spent','3','icecream','2020-08-18 20:00']
]
```

So, I need to change `balance` value and append a list into `balance_logs`.
Also I may add more data into db.py, so it will be good if I won't need to `<copy file contents fully -> modify the parts you need -> dump into file, by fully recreating it>` method.

Comment: you can redirect the output of your python script to your db.py using sys module

Comment: Python files are not meant to be used as data storage. You should use a format like JSON or CSV or SQLite which have much better support for writing new data.

Comment: You have tagged the question with `json`, so apparently you already had this idea. Was there any particular problem when you tried to use JSON?

Comment: Yeah, I got very confused trying to use it :) Also, can't seem to find a way to update data in file, or append new into existing list. It just rewrites the file fully. I am new into python, so sorry.

Comment: *It just rewrites the file fully* - that's how it works. You are doing it correctly.

Comment: Oh, got it thanks)) Will try to solve  using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what I mean, saving this file in json format I believe would be ok. There are tutorials about this online, however I will try to summarise the basics here. To open and correctly load data from json, you can use:

```
import json 
with open('example.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

To save data to a file, you can use:

```
import json
with open('example.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

To append data with json, you can use a mix of these two, for example taking a part of the dictionary stored in the json, operating on it and then saving it again. An example is:

```
import json 
with open('example.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Do something to the data, for example...
data['foo'] = 'bar'

with open('example.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was trying not use json and also, when I used json it rewrote the file fully, it seemed not so effetive, but I guess that's the only way to do what I want. Thank you!)